# Can DNS redirect all HTTPS traffic to a specific IIS application

Tags: domain-name-system, iis

Is it possible to use DNS to redirect all HTTPS traffic to a specific IIS website irrespective of the TLD?

**EDIT:** I have another post where I was dealing with this issue separately: [All HTTPS traffic redirecting to one IIS site](https://serverfault.com/questions/520839/all-https-traffic-redirecting-to-one-iis-site)
The other post was from the server point of view not DNS.

Regards,
Jacques

Comment: More details please.

Comment: DNS is just something that looks up a hostname and resolves it to an IP address. This has nothing to do with the actual application or service. So DNS itself can't do any redirection. Could you please add more details to your question?

Comment: we have a certificate configured on a single application in our webserver but for some reason another application is redirecting to that application/site when you add HTTPS as the protocol. Please see my other post - http://serverfault.com/questions/520839/all-https-traffic-redirecting-to-one-iis-site

Comment: I've added the other posts details to this one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, DNS only knows about hostnames. It knows nothing about HTTPS, IIS, etc.

You can setup a specific hostname which points to your website and then have IIS enforce HTTPS only.

Comment: @Jacques sounds completely different from what you are asking in this question. It looks to me like it is a question about IIS configuration which I am blissfully unaware of :)

Comment: ok thanks Martin. This question actually stemmed from that question. We're checking all avenues for where the problem can be coming from. Thanks again